# Why do I need to unsubscribe to `onAuthStateChanged` in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I was following a tutorial about creating google sign in. He said that you need to use the `onAuthStateChanged` to listen to a sign-in/out. The part where I failed to understand is when he said that the method is like 'an open subscription' and we need to 'closed the subscription' to prevent memory leaks.

So before you look at the code, things that I can't grasp are these:

1. why we need to define `unsubscribeFromAuth` ;
2. why we need to assign the `onAuthStateChanged` to `this.unsubscribeFromAuth` in ComponentDidMount ;
3. why we need to use ComponentWillUnmount and call the `unsubscribeFromAuth`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    }
  }

  unsubscribeFromAuth = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user })
      console.log(user)
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth()
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks.

When you initialise `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` you create a listener. If you don't unsubscribe then this listener will continue to listen even after you stop using it. This will waste memory.

To prevent this from happening, you unsubscribe from listener when you unmount your app.

In order to unsubscribe you need something to unsubscribe from. This is why you assign the listener to a variable in `ComponentDidMount`. This allows you to refer to the variable when you want to unsubscribe.

I hope this puts your 3 questions into context.

Here are two talks that cover the topic in a bit more detail.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRoR_0K586I
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uumc9RvSeco
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJRbZdtKmxU